# I need help merging two videos with ffpmeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing

I get an error when I try to merge two videos with FFMPEG.
It should take the resolution etc. from the first video.
I get the following error:

> Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 1080x1920, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1080x1920, SAR 4:5)

My console arguments are:

```
-y -i "/home/test/Videos/Videos/First Video.mp4" -i "/home/test/Videos/Videos/Reference_Sub_884.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]scale2ref=iw:-2[v0][v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out]" -map "[out]" -r 30 -b:v 2M "/home/test/Videos/Output/First Video.mp4_Reference_Sub_884.mp4"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why is this tagged C#? And .net? Seems unrelated but a pure FFMPEG issue?

Comment: Because I call it out from C#.

Comment: Does it make a difference if it's called directly from cmd or through .Net?

Comment: No, I've changed the tags to the correct one.

Comment: , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.
I’m voting to close this question because